# Page Not Found Error in Header of WordPress Blog

Tags: php, html, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I'm working on a WordPress site and a weird thing is happening in the header.

It's giving me one of these above the header and content:

[image]

This is a GoDaddy message when a page is not found (I believe?). I figured that since this is WordPress, it's a PHP include that's just not there or was moved. Here's the source code for that area. It's a table (and again, I'm under the assumption that it's being dynamically generated):

```
<table width="85%" border="1" bordercolor="#000000" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td bgcolor="#e5dccd">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td width="40%"><img src="http://images.godaddy.com/hosting/hdr_sorry_small.gif" border="1" bordercolor="#000000"></td>
                    <td align="CENTER"><h2 style="font-family: arial, sans-serif">Page Not Found</h2></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
             </table>
            </td>
            </tr>
         <tr>
         <td>
             <p style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; font-size: 10pt; font-family: arial, sans-serif">
             The page you tried to access does not exist on this server. This page may not exist due to the following reasons:
             </p><ol><li style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: arial, sans-serif"><strong>You arethe owner of this web site and you have not uploaded</strong> (or incorrectly uploaded) your web site. For information on uploading your web site using FTP client software or web design software, <a href="http://ftphelp.secureserver.net/index.html">click here for FTP Upload Information</a>. 
             <p>
             </p></li><li style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: arial, sans-serif"><strong>The URL that you have entered in your browser is incorrect.</strong> Please re-enter the URL and try again.<p>
             </p></li><li style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: arial, sans-serif"><strong>The Link that you clicked on incorrectly points to this page.</strong> Please contact the owner of this web site to inform them of this situation.</li></ol>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
<div id="main">
```

I know it's a little messy but I'm just showing that it's a table that's being generated. The reason I show this is because here is the code that's in the WordPress template:

```
<body <?php if(function_exists('body_class')) body_class(); ?>>
<div id="main">
```

You'll see that between body and div id="main" there's no content. This table is being generated there though. So I don't know what link is broken or how to track down what needs fixing at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This looks like some kind of iframe. I've never seen WordPress add something like this. Can you share a url to your site?

Comment: Yeah the site is newellstrength.com (a client). It looks like an iFrame but I don't know why it would be generated because there is nothing in the code to infer that that would happen.

Comment: I've never seen this before. There is something that is adding this content to what should be the `<head>` of your document. I think you've got to disable all plugins and see if this goes away. If so, enable them one by one. If not, make sure your theme's `header.php` isn't corrupted.

Comment: Ok yeah, good call on the plugins. I'll try that. Thanks, great idea!

Answer (score 0):

Click on Active on main account page 
under hosting
when u click on Active it will show suspend option as shown in pic below
[![godaddy hosting error][1]][1]

Comment: Something went wrong with your image. I can't see it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to provide more explanation to your answers. You also do not have the reputation yet to post images, you may want to just use a link for now. See [How to answer page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for help in improving your answer.